# SQL Server Profiler Writes vs RowCounts

Tags: sql-server, profiler, rowcount

When I measure Writes and RowCounts in SQL Server Profiler, I have found one statement (a delete) that is reporting Writes = 26035, but RowCounts of 0.  How is this possible?  Clearly, the statement is deleting rows since it is writing, so why are none of these counted in the rowcount column?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this, but just can't get it working. Could you post the code of the delete statement?

Comment: Sorry I don't have permission to post the exact code, but here's a generic version:

DELETE table1 FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.account = table2.account

Comment: OK, I think I've figured it out - the delete statement is deleting nothing, but Profiler is showing writes because SQL Server is creating a temp table behind the scenes due to the size of the datasets it's dealing with.

Comment: When using your delete and having a hashtable in the query plan still shows no writes in the profiler output.

Comment: My database tables are huge -  millions of rows. That might have something to do with the query analyzers choice of hashtable?

Comment: I tested on 2 tables with 5 million rows. I can blow them up further if needed.

Comment: My execution plan does show a hash match, so this seems to be the best (only?) explanation. It definitely isn't updating rows, as I've checked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Because rowcount points to the number of rows returned to the client. And a delete doesn't return any rows unless you use the `OUTPUT` clause.</strike>

Update: ==> I stand corrected Testing shows the rowcount is also set when a delete does not return rows.

Proof:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Accounts 
 WHERE Category= 'COA'  
   AND Code between 1500 and 2000 
-- 18 Reads, 0 Writes, 51 RowCount

DELETE FROM Accounts 
 WHERE Category = 'COA' 
   AND Code between 1500 and 2000
-- 22 Reads, 1 Writes, 51 RowCount

DELETE FROM Accounts
OUTPUT DELETED.* 
WHERE Category = 'COA' 
  AND Code between 2000 and 4000
-- 24 Reads, 3 Writes, 103 RowCount
```

Running a delete statement on 2 tables with 5 million records which removes no records give me the following query plan::

```
delete clust from clust, heap where clust.Key= heap.Key
-- 19854 Reads, 0 Writes, 0 RowCount
```

> ```
>  |--Clustered Index Delete(OBJECT:([dbo].[clust].[idx_clust]), OBJECT:([dbo].[clust].[idx2_clust]))
>       |--Top(ROWCOUNT est 0)
>            |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
>                 |--Hash Match(Right Semi Join, HASH:([dbo].[heap].[Key])=([dbo].[clust].[Key]))
>                      |--Bitmap(HASH:([dbo].[heap].[Key]), DEFINE:([Bitmap1012]))
>                      |    |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([dbo].[heap].[Key]))
>                      |         |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([dbo].[heap].[Key]))
>                      |              |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[heap].[idx_heap]), ORDERED FORWARD)
>                      |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([dbo].[clust].[Key]))
>                          |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[clust].[idx2_clust]),  WHERE:(PROBE([Bitmap1012],[dbo].[clust].[Key],N'[IN ROW]')) ORDERED FORWARD)
> ```

Running the same query on 2 small tables with 10 rows each gives the following results:

```
delete smallclust from smallclust, smallheap where smallclust.srp_key = smallheap.common_key
-- 45 Reads, 0 Writes, 0 RowCount
```

> ```
>  |--Table Delete(OBJECT:([dbo].[smallclust]))
>       |--Top(ROWCOUNT est 0)
>            |--Nested Loops(Left Semi Join, WHERE:([dbo].[smallheap].[Key]=[dbo].[smallclust].[Key]))
>                 |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[smallclust]))
>                 |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([dbo].[smallheap]))
> ```

So the assumption of the hash table causing the writes remains inconclusive.

Comment: Yeah, my sproc has a bunch of other deletes that all show an appropriate rowcount returned, so it definitely should be returning a rowcount.